# Зубчатый (ступенчатый) массив и linq

Tags: c#, массивы, linq

Решил подробнее изучить linq и возник такой вопрос, как сделать выборку из зубчатого массива?

Допустим, есть массив

```
string[][] zmass = new string[5][];

zmass[0] = new string[4] { "a", "b", "s", "d" };
zmass[1] = new string[3] { "e", "f", "g" };
zmass[2] = new string[5] { "h", "i", "f", "k", "f" };
zmass[3] = new string[6] { "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r" };
zmass[4] = new string[2] { "s", "t" };
```

Хочу выбрать из них буквы, которые повторяются, и в какой строке (например, буква f встречается один раз в [1] строке и два раза в [2])

В предыдущем моем вопросе мне подсказали код для одномерного массива:

```
var result = array
         .Select(str => new { Name = str, Count = array.Count(s => s == str)})
         .Where(obj => obj.Count > 1)
         .Distinct()
         .ToDictionary(obj => obj.Name, obj => obj.Count)
```

Пытался я его переделать для зубчатого, но так ничего и не вышло =( 
Подскажите плз, как надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно решить этот вопрос, например, следующим образом *(разумеется, это не `production-ready` решение, а просто набросок).*

Кстати, чтобы не перебирать кучу всего на каждую операцию (из-за ленивости `LINQ'a`), вам стоит расставить вызовы `ToList()` в правильных местах.

```
        var jaggedArray = new string[5][];
        jaggedArray[0] = new[] { "a", "b", "s", "d" };
        jaggedArray[1] = new[] { "e", "f", "g" };
        jaggedArray[2] = new[] { "h", "i", "f", "k", "f" };
        jaggedArray[3] = new[] { "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r" };
        jaggedArray[4] = new[] { "s", "t" };

        // Общий набор символов из всех элементов ступенчатого массива.
        var flattened = jaggedArray.SelectMany(row => row);

        // Проведем трансформацию следующего вида:
        // элемент -> { элемент, ряд, количество вхождений в этом ряду }
        var onlyRepeating = jaggedArray.SelectMany(row => row.Select(
            value =>
            new
                {
                    Value = value,
                    RowIndex = jaggedArray.ToList().IndexOf(row),
                    CountInThisRow = row.Count(x => x == value),
                }))
            // Нужно взять 'distinct', поскольку иначе, например, для 'f' в третьей
            // строчке будут два вхождения, а нам нужно только одно.
            .Distinct()
            // Возьмем только те элементы, которые хоть где-то повторяются.
            .Where(entry => flattened.Count(x => x == entry.Value) > 1);

        // На этом этапе в 'grouped' будут совпадения вида
        // { повторившийся хоть раз элемент, все вхождения в отдельные строки }.
        // *** Это наш финальный результат. ***
        var grouped = onlyRepeating.GroupBy(entry => entry.Value);

        foreach (var grouping in grouped)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Matches for '{0}':", grouping.Key);

            foreach (var groupingDetails in grouping)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t Row {0} - {1} matched",
                    groupingDetails.RowIndex, groupingDetails .CountInThisRow);
            }
        }
```

Comment: .SelectMany(row => row.Select ...
маленький вопрос, что хранится в row? берётся вся строка массива и подаётся на оператор select(а он уже разбирает по элементам) или в row только конкретное значение массива?

Comment: опять же:
в ``.SelectMany()`` тоже можно использовать индексы:

    jaggedArray.SelectMany((row, index) => row.Select(
            value =>
            new
                {
                    Value = value,
                    RowIndex = index,
                    CountInThisRow = row.Count(x => x == value),
                }))

т.о. избавиться от лишнего ``.ToList()``

Comment: @Spectre Да, забыл. Думаю, правда, что `.ToList()` соптимизится, но все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Еще вариант:

```
        //индексируем по столбцам в каждой строке
        var indexByCols = zmass.Select(x => x.Select((y, i) => 
                                            new { index = i, value = y }));
        //дополнительно индексируем по строкам
        var indexByRows = indexByCols.SelectMany((x, i) => 
                          x.Select(y => 
                          new { row = i, col = y.index, value = y.value }));
        //группируем по буквам и выводим повторы
        var repeats = indexByRows.ToLookup(x => x.value)
            .Select(x => new {key = x.Key, positions = x.ToList()})
            .Where(x => x.positions.Count > 1);

        foreach (var rep in repeats)
        {
            foreach(var position in rep.positions)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : строка:{1} символ:{2}", rep.key, position.row, position.col);
        }
```